# Managed Property missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

I am trying to search using managed property .

I had created terms in termstore management ex -COUNTRY-india,usa.

I had created site columns using managed metadata Country

add site column in document library and inserted one value like doc1 and country india

now if i go to search schema i can see ows_COUNTRY crawled property but my managed property is blank

But search automatically create managed property for site column having value.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that "now if i go to search schema i can see ows_COUNTRY crawled property but my managed property is blank."

Do you mean the managed property is created, but it doesn't mapped o the crawled property？
Or do you mean the managed property is not created?

From the official article: The search schema displays the name of auto-generated managed properties and their mappings to crawled properties in grey in the search schema. The search schema doesn't hold the settings of the managed auto-generated managed properties. The settings exist, but they're hidden from the search schema.

That means that the managed property mappings to crawled property. But they're hidden from the search schema.

Manage the search schema in SharePoint Online for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema

Comment: In managed property I can see owstaxidCountry and if I click it it says it is autogenerated managed property

Comment: Search automatically created the owstaxIdCounty managed property, but can't display the actual automatic settings and mappings here. Instead it displays all settings as disabled, and no mappings. If you add a crawled property mapping here, search adds it to the automatic mappings. <a href='javascript:void window.open("https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx")'>Learn how</a> you can see which crawled property was automatically mapped to this managed property. If you change a setting here, search overwrites all the automatic settings and mappings with those displayed here.

Comment: It is by default that  the mapping is hidding in auto-generated managed properties, you can check the crawled property to see the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. The site columns that have value for them **managed property** will be created automatically.

From MSDN:

"In SharePoint, only site columns that contain values will automatically become managed properties when they are crawled. Regular columns will not automatically become managed properties when they are crawled."

**Site column type,**   **Site column name,**   **Crawled property name,**  **Managed property name**

Managed Metadata,      Site Column Name,    **ows_taxId_SiteColumnName**, **owstaxIdSiteColumnName**

You can search the managed property for the manage metadata column with the below text:

**owstaxId**

Generally, it takes 24 to 72 hours to get it reflected for new managed property in SharePoint online. If this already crosses this time - you can raise a ticket to Microsoft help desk support.

MSDN Source:

[Automatically created managed properties in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/automatically-created-managed-properties-in-sharepoint)

Comment: i can see "owstaxIdCountry" in ,managed property but its not map to crawled property "ows_country" ? its this is the one or there will be another property to be generated after 24 hrs

Comment: Yes, this is the one and its should map automatically. Try to map this with the crawl property manually.